# Is there any example from physics, supporting $\int_0^1\frac1xdx=\int_1^\infty\frac1xdx$?

Tags: renormalization, integration, singularities, regularization, volume

This question is related to the potential possibilities of classification of divergent integrals more precisely than just "divergent to infinity" and the like. Improper divergent integrals can have many distinguishing properties, like germ at infinity, rate of grow and regularized value.
A separate question is whether we can talk about equivalence (in whatever sense) of integrals divergent at infinity and those divergent at a singularity or pole.

For instance, formally applying the Laplace transform we can establish the following formal relations (for $n>0$):

$$\int_0^1 x^{-1+n} dx=\int_1^\infty n!x^{-1-n}dx$$

and

$$\int_1^\infty x^{-1+n} dx=\int_0^1 n!x^{-1-n}dx$$

This works for convergent integrals:

$$\int_0^1 dx=\int_1^\infty \frac1{x^2}dx=1$$

If generalized to divergent integrals, it also seems to work well, the equality

$$\int_1^\infty dx=\int_0^1 \frac1{x^2}dx$$

seems to be supported well by the hyperfunction theory.

But with $n=0$ we have (in the both formulas):

$$\int_0^1 \frac1x dx=\int_1^\infty \frac1x dx$$

This looks counter-intuitive at the first glance, as the figures under the integrals are identical up to a reflection relative the $y=x$ axis, except the first one has an additional $1\times 1$ square.

Of course, since the integrals are divergent, it should not be an obstacle to the identity (as the positions of the figures and the limits of integration are different). The both integrals are regularizable to the value $0$.

So, I wonder, if there is any exmple from physics where these integrals demonstrate equivalence in a more strict sense than being both divergent to infinity?

**UPDATE**

Now it is clear to me that this equality **should not hold**. Rather, the following cries to be correct: $\int_0^1 \frac1x dx=\gamma +\int_1^\infty \frac1x dx$.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than
$$
\int_0^1 \frac1x dx=\int_1^\infty \frac1x dx
$$
in differential renormalizaton (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9610025)), we have
$$
\int_0^1 \frac1x dx=-\int_1^\infty \frac1x dx
$$
where
$$
\int_0^1 \frac1x dx = - \ln\Lambda_0 \\
\int_1^\infty \frac1x dx = \ln\Lambda_\infty
$$
assuming $\Lambda_0 = \Lambda_\infty$.

If $\int_0^1 \frac1x dx < 0$ is hard to grasp, try this
$$
\zeta(-1) = 1 + 2 + 3 + ... = -1/12.
$$

It's all in a day's work for the loopy bunch of theoretical physicists.

Comment: The last equality gives the regularized value of the series ($-\frac1{12}$). But these both integrals have the regularized value zero. So, this is not the same thing.

Comment: Also, why do you assume $\Lambda_0=\Lambda_\infty$?

Comment: What happened to the integration constant? This kind of manipulation only makes sense in a _physical_ context. Mathematically you are equating two infinities. Their difference is probably infinite, too.

Comment: @Anixx, the logarithmic divergent integrals can NOT be regularized to zero, albeit other divergent integral can (i.e. quadratic divergent integral equals zero in dimensional regularization). If you equate the logarithmic divergent integrals to zero, there wouldn't be renormalization group running any more. You apparently don't want that, do you?

Comment: Look here for why the logarithmic integral regularizes to zero: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3893672/

Comment: Also, your linked paper makes other strange claims that may be explained only by use of some strange notation. For instance, that $\int_0^1 \frac1{r^3}\,dr=\frac12$ (the regularized value of this is $0$ due to Laplace transform). Or that $\int_0^\infty dr$ has singularity at $r=0$ (no, I do not see a singularity there).

Comment: @Anixx, of course you can set the integral to zero mathematically. For instance, I can set $\Lambda_0 = \Lambda_\infty = 1$. But you are talking about physics applications here, right?  In physics, the logarithmic integrals are always transmuted into log of a scale (renormalization scale). A conformally invariant (massless) classical theory would acquire a scale via quantum fluctuations. For example, in the QCD, the scale $\Lambda_{QCD}$ can appeal out of nowhere, even if the quarks are massless.

Comment: Possibly these equalities mean regularized values at some non-1 scale? Then I cannot comment. In formula (32) your linked paper gives the right regularization of the integral.

Comment: Well, after thinking of it, yes, if we change the scale, the intersection of the logarithmic graphic with x axis will move left or right from $x=1$ and indeed, the regularized values would be $\text{reg}\int_0^1 1/xdx=-\text{reg}\int_1^\infty1/xdx$. This is simply because $\text{reg}\int_0^\infty 1/xdx=0$. So yes, in the sense of regularized values these integrals are different only in sign. But my question more concerned the "infinite part" than the regularized value.